# How do I make MODI not identify rotated images?

Tags: vbscript, ms-office, modi

I have a VBScript script that looks like this:

```
Const ForAppending = 8
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\OCRresults.txt", ForAppending, True)
set miDoc=CreateObject("MODI.Document")
miDoc.Create ("C:\PathToTifScreenshot.tif")
miDoc.Images(0).OCR
set miLayout = miDoc.Images(0).Layout
stringOut=miLayout.Text
objTextFile.WriteLine stringOut
DoOCR = stringOut
Set miLayout = Nothing
Set miDoc = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

It uses MODI to OCR a tif file. However, MODI automatically identifies rotated images and I do not want it to work this way. What I basically want is for it to OCR properly only when the image is properly rotated. There is an option in the gui of MODI that you can uncheck: "Auto Rotate", but it seems that this only works for the manual process. Any ideas how I can prevent my script from identifying rotated images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MODI's [`OCR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa202819.aspx) method has three parameters:

```
expression.OCR(LangId, OCROrientImage, OCRStraightenImage)
```

The description for the 2nd parameter, *OCROrientImage*, states:

> **OCROrientImage** Optional **Boolean**. Specifies whether the OCR engine attempts to determine the orientation of the page. Default is **true**.

Try setting this parameter to False and see if it helps.